# "mmal: main: Failed to create camera component mmal: Failed to run camera app" error while using Arducam IMX219 with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I want to use arducam IMX219 with raspberry pi for image processing. When i give the command

`sudo raspistill -o myImage.jpg`

It throws the error

```
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

I have tried

```
sudo rpi update
sudo raspi-config and enabling the camera module
increasing gpu to 144
changing the cable for camera
tried installing libcamera
tried using picamera in python
```

Please help me to overcome this. I am in desperate need of a solution.

Comment: Is the camera detected with `sudo vcgencmd get_camera` ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/